# How to Sum Horizontal Values Depending on Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to sum "Main" and "Second" under TOTAL if the "CHECK" is "YES". This continues until 100 so I have to use range formulas. Is there a way?

Comment: So, your result will be `4`. Am I right?

Comment: @Harun24hr It will be "2" under TOTAL/Main and "2" under TOTAL/Second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Main` try-

```
=SUM(TOCOL(--(C2:K2="Main")*--(E2:K2="Check")*(E3:K3="Yes")*(C3:K3),3))
```

For `Second` try-

```
=SUM(TOCOL(--(C2:K2="Second")*--(D2:K2="Check")*(D3:K3="Yes")*(C3:K3),3))
```

[image]

Comment: I get #NAME? error with those formulas. I use Excel 2019.

Comment: @LordPermaximum If you are on `Excel-2019` then try `=SUM(IFERROR(--(C2:K2="Main")*--(E2:K2="Check")*(E3:K3="Yes")*(C3:K3),0))`. You may need to enter the formula as array means press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after putting the formula into the cell.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT would bypass the need for `ctrl+shift+enter`. (But most importantly I wanted to compliment you on your new hat).

Comment: @P.b `SUMPRODUCT()` needs same length array. I used little tricky length for `Check`. That is reason to avoid sumproduct.

Comment: Harun24hr, thanks that worked.
@P.b It didn't get rid of the need for ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: @LordPermaximum That means your excel support dynamic spill array approach. Great!

Comment: Didn't see that. Clever.